# How can I input text or data in TextBox with Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, input

HTML on page 1

```
<input id="j_username" tabindex="1" name="j_username" type="text" class="default field">
```

The following code works:

```
ie.document.getelementsbyname("j_username").Item.innertext = "Userid"
```

But for this HTML code, how do I input text?

```
<input type="text" value="" size="40" maxlength="110" name="prop_456698_101587" org_value="" onmouseover="onDynMouseOver(document.server.prop_456698_101587,false);" onclick="onDynClick(document.server.prop_456698_101587,false,'456698','101587');" onblur="checkChanged(document.server.prop_456698_101587);" style="cursor: auto;">
```

This code doesn't work:

```
ie.document.getelementsbyname("prop_456698_109745").Item.innertext = "TEXTINPUT"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: Shouldn't your `getelementsbyname("prop_456698_109745")` use the same name (`"prop_456698_101587"`) that is in the HTML?